# How can I dynamically create a tweet button?

Tags: javascript, twitter, dhtml

I'm currently trying to create a tweet button with the horizontal count feature dynamically:

**JavaScript**

```
var twitter = document.createElement('a');
twitter.setAttribute('href', 'http://twitter.com/share');
twitter.setAttribute('class', 'twitter-share-button twitter-tweet');
twitter.setAttribute('data-url','http://mindcloud.co.uk/idea/?idea=' + this.id);
twitter.setAttribute('data-count', 'horizontal');
twitter.setAttribute('data-via', 'jtbrowncouk');
twitter.style.top = '20px';
twitter.style.left = '300px';
twitter.innerHTML = "Tweet";
```

The problem i'm having is that the button is being displayed as a text link, not as a button with the horizontal count box.

I've created a facebook button in the same way, which works correctly, however to make it work I use the following:

**JavaScript**

```
var facebook = document.createElement('fb:like');
facebook.setAttribute('id', 'like'+this.id);
facebook.setAttribute('href', 'http://mindcloud.co.uk/idea/?idea=' + this.id);    
facebook.setAttribute('layout', 'button_count');
facebook.setAttribute('send', 'false');        
facebook.setAttribute('width' , '300');
facebook.setAttribute('font', '');
facebook.setAttribute('show_faces', 'true');
facebook.style.top = '0px';
facebook.style.left = '300px';
```

using the following:

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

to parse and draw the button. `FB.XFBML.parse()` comes from 
http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js

When I create the Tweet button statically inside a .html file it works correctly. I'm including the following script within my index page where the tweet button should be created dynamically:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

If you can see what i'm doing incorrectly please inform me!

The following screenshot gives a visual explanation to what is going wrong with the tweet button!
[image: Tweet button not displaying correctly.]

**Solution:**

I've now managed to solve the problem. The problem i'd imagine is that the twitter script is running on load, and not being re-run upon creating the element.

using the following jQuery works correctly!

$.getScript("http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js");

Comment: you should put place the solution as an answer and close the question

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's worth noting that as of recently you can use the following twitter widget function:

```
twttr.widgets.load();
```

Assuming you've loaded the widgets.js file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

This will dynamically re-create the tweet button for you.

Comment: This is actually a better solution, if you just want the script to (re)create the button, instead of forcing a re-load.

Answer (score 6):

I've now managed to solve the problem. The problem i'd imagine is that the twitter script is running on load, and not being re-run upon creating the element.

using the following jQuery works correctly!

```
$.getScript("http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js");
```

Answer (score 2):

You're just using the wrong code. To specify the URL, you use url, not data-url. This works:

```
var twitter = document.createElement('a');
twitter.setAttribute('href', 'http://twitter.com/share');
twitter.setAttribute('class', 'twitter-share-button twitter-tweet');
twitter.setAttribute('url','http://mindcloud.co.uk/idea/?idea=' + this.id);
twitter.setAttribute('data-count', 'horizontal');
twitter.setAttribute('data-via', 'jtbrowncouk');
twitter.style.top = '20px';
twitter.style.left = '300px';
twitter.innerHTML = "Tweet";
```

For more details, check out Twitter's documentation at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button#properties

Comment: Thanks for the info on the url, but the main problem i'm having is with the tweet button appearing as text. I've taken a screenshot to show you what I mean.

http://i.imgur.com/J1qoA.png

Comment: Which browser are you using? This works for me in Chrome
EDIT: Just tried it in Firefox. I see what you mean. I'll see if I can help.

Comment: @Jack could you try starting the Firefox console? I'm getting some CSS stylesheet errors from Twitter's twimg.com domain.
EDIT: Suddenly, I'm getting no more warnings, but the problem remains. :/

Comment: It seems to work for me in Firefox 4 and Chrome. I've not tested my website in other browsers fully yet, i'm planning to make a working version in Chrome and refactor it.

Comment: Maybe because I'm using Firefox 5 then. I hate cross browser testing. Really annoys me a lot. Best of luck!