# Creating a tweet button after page load

Tags: javascript, twitter

I need to create multiple tweet buttons, after the page has loaded. Each button will be tweeting a url that is different from the page that they sit on. I understand that I need to append an appropriate data-url attribute to each tweet button, to achieve this.

But, the Twitter API doesn't seem to provide a straight-forward way to do the above, dynamically, using Javascript, after page load. I've seen a couple of suggestions on StackOverflow and other sites, which hint at re-loading the widgets.js script whenever a new tweet button needs to be created: [How can I dynamically create a tweet button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981905/how-can-i-dynamically-create-a-tweet-button)

Are there any other options to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automatically compose a tweet on behalf of the user by redirecting them to a URL that looks like the following:

http://twitter.com/home?status=Hey+check+out+this+cool+site+http://www.stackoverflow.com/

So in answer to your question - if i've understood correctly - you could just create a couple of different anchors with that link as the HREF:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=Hey+check+out+this+cool+site+http://www.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">Tweet about Link a</a>
```

EDIT:

Upon further investigation, it's actually pretty easy to use the tweet button with count for different URLs by setting some `data` attributes

I knocked up a quick jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/rghCG/

More info about what you can do with the tweet button: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of this alternative method to compose tweets! For my situation this works perfectly. But, the only disadvantage with this method is that I can't use the tweet button plugin's features like tweet count etc.