# Tweet button looks like a normal <a> link without any JS or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, twitter

I am trying to embed the Tweet button in my website, I already added

```js
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

inside `<head>`, widgets.js gets included normally and everything looks fine when i put

```xml
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-size="large" data-count="none">Tweet</a>
```

But the problem is, When i use

```js
$('.someclasses').append('<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-butto ...</a>');
```

the button will be appended, but this time it doesn't looks fine, But looks like a normal  link without any CSS or JS effects, As well as the link guide me to https://twitter.com/share

Any solutions ? Thanks :)

Comment: Is the `...` in your `$('.someclasses').append` line intentionally unique to this question post or in your code, too?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981905/how-can-i-dynamically-create-a-tweet-button

Comment: @PaulS. Nah im trying to represent "Till the end of the code" because its long a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, The solution for this is to put this code under the appended `<a>` element :

`twttr.widgets.load();`

Answer (score 1):

you need to re-apply the twitter script. After you append your new elements try this snippet:

```
$('.someclasses > a.twitter-share-button').each(function() {
    var tweet_button = new twttr.TweetButton(this);
    tweet_button.render();
});
```

Comment: it shows me the error with this line  `var tweet_button = new twttr.TweetButton(this);`... the error says `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`  using google chrome developers kit

Answer (score 0):

I had the Disconnect extension in Chrome. I figured this out the hard way after struggling for hours. After removing it, it worked fine. Didn't even need to close Chrome windows.